# How to properly align the line without equal sign with the other lines

Tags: math-mode, alignment

I would like to write an equation of the form

```
    formula 1
 =  formula 2
 =  formula 3
    ...
```

However, I'm having difficulty aligning the first line with the other lines. I tried `\quad` or even `\mathbin{\phantom{=}}`, but the spacing is not the same as with `=`.

How can I properly align the first line?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &\quad \{ f \colon A \to B \} \\
    % &\mathbin{\phantom{=}} \{ f \colon A \to B \} \\
    &= \{ g \colon C \to D \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\{` as the alignment point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
       &\{ f \colon A \to B \} \\
    ={}&\{ g \colon C \to D \}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```